# mongo push to array in aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following code:

```js
  const newArray = [];
  companies.items.forEach(async (item) => {
    if (item.parentCompanyID) {
      newArray.push({
        updateOne: {
          filter: { id: item?.parentCompanyID },
          update: [
            {
              $push: {
                branches: {
                  id: item?.id,
                  name: item.companyName,
                  parentId: item?.parentCompanyID,
                  type: item.companyType,
                  active: item.isActive,
                  number: item.companyNumber,
                  newlyAdded: { $eq: [{ $type: '$newlyAdded' }, 'missing'] },
                },
              },
            },
          ],
          upsert: true,
        },
      });
    } else {
      newArray.push({
        updateOne: {
          filter: { id: item?.id },
          update: [
            {
              $set: {
                id: item?.id,
                name: item.companyName,
                parentId: item?.parentCompanyID,
                type: item.companyType,
                active: item.isActive,
                number: item.companyNumber,
                newlyAdded: { $eq: [{ $type: '$newlyAdded' }, 'missing'] },
              },
            },
          ],
          upsert: true,
        },
      });
    }
  });
  await Company.bulkWrite(newArray);
```

This will go through company.items and for each will add updateOne into newArray which will the goes to bulkWrite.

My problem lies with `$push` as this needs to be in aggregation pipeline, and when i add the brackets around `update` it will break with `MongooseError: Invalid update pipeline operator: "$push"`

Iam sure the script could be simplified but iam still fairly new to mongoDB. What i need is this to insert to Company if the item hasnt got parentCompanyID, if it does have than push to branches array for the relevant Company with id of parentCompanyID.

Sample data from company.items array:

```json
{
id: 5,
name: "Sports"
parentCompanyID: null
},
{
id: 51,
name: "Football"
parentCompanyID: 5
}
```

And MongoDB for COmpany should look like this:

```json
{
id: 5,
name: "Sports",
parentCompanyID: null,
branches: [{
   id: 51,
   name: "Football",
   parentCompanyID: 5
}]
}
```

Hope this makes sense. ANy help would be appreciated. I could not find any similar issue and only one i came accross was to use `$concatArrays` but this wouldnt work either.

Thank you

EDIT:
as per @Takis_ answer thsi now sort of works. Only problem is when $concatArrays does it jobs its not pushing into array as expected from `$push`. this is the result as of now, insted of branches being one array it has nested arrays. if there are more branches it follows same patter and it could end up with many nested arrays rather than 1 array of objects. any ideas?

```json
{
  "id": 29683585,
  "name": "123",
  "parentId": null,
  "newlyAdded": true,
  "branches": [
    [
      null,
      {
        "id": 29693873,
        "name": "245",
        "parentId": 29683585
      }
    ],
    {
      "id": 29695646,
      "name": "789",
      "parentId": 29683585
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `$push` aggregate operator works in `$group`,but `$concatArrays` can do the same, if you do `{$concatArrays : [ "$myarray" , [new-member] ]}` (make it array first the member to add)
But its slow for big arrays, for example if you do like 1000 of them in a `$reduce` but here you do only 1 , so it will be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been sorted. Thanks to [Takis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4882692/takis) and his pointing to `$concatArrays` i was able to make this works.

Working code is below:

```js
 newArray.push({
        updateOne: {
          filter: { id: item?.parentCompanyID },
          update: [
            {
              $set: {
                branches: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                    { $ifNull: ['$branches', []] },
                    [
                      {
                        id: item?.id,
                        name: item.companyName,
                        parentId: item?.parentCompanyID,
                        type: item.companyType,
                        active: item.isActive,
                        number: item.companyNumber,
                        newlyAdded: { $ne: ['$newlyAdded', null] },
                      },
                    ],
                  ],
                },
              },
            },
          ],
          upsert: true,
        },
      });
```